# Keeping symbology unaffected by data frame rotation in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, symbology, rotate

In ArcMap 10.3, I am trying to recreate a city planning map that uses a lot of crosshatched and line-based symbology for different elements in the map legend like so:

[image: Figure 1]

No projection information is provided, so I assume that the authors rotated the data frame slightly (~17 degrees) from the original map projection orientation to keep boundaries horizontally straight.

In my emulation attempt, I have rotated the data frame. However, doing this has the effect of also rotating the symbology, causing symbols that appear straight in my legend to become offset by the angle of rotation as shown in this zoomed in re-creation of the previous image:

[image]

Is there any way to make the symbology independent of the data frame's angle of rotation?

The angle of lines can be edited **manually** in the symbology options and offset by the data frame's angle, however, I was wondering if there is an **automatic** option for this.

Comment: As far as I know, your workaround (rotating the lines manually in the symbology settings) is the only way to do this for polygon features. There is a setting for this in the ArcMap Advanced Settings Utility, but it only works for marker symbols (for points), not polygon fill patterns.

Comment: Create a copy of unrotated data frame and show its elements in the legend or simply convert legend to graphics

Comment: @FelixIP  With an extra sentence or two, like mentioning that the unrotated data frame could be off the page, I think your comment would make an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @FelixIP you could:

> Create a copy of unrotated data frame and show its elements in the
>   legend or simply convert legend to graphics

The unrotated data frame could be off the page.